# Having issue converting response in UTF-8 format

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, decode

I am getting an error with this line:

```
Data(from: responseValue.utf8 as! Decoder)
```

[image])

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data'

```
do{
    let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(forget_Base.self, from: Data(from: responseValue.utf8 as! Decoder))
    if responseData.code == 200
    {
        let message = isNilValue(assignValue: responseData.message)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {(_action) -> Void in
            let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SetPasswordVCSID")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next!, animated: true)
        })
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
catch
{
    print("error")
}
```

How can I resolve it? I already tried too many things but I am stuck with it.

Comment: what magic is this: `responseValue.utf8 as! Decoder`? what result do you have if you just use `responseValue`?

Comment: What is `responseValue`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Getting response from API

Comment: @Lu_ I am not getting any response just because it is not compiling due to error I attached screenshot. Please check

Comment: I meant, what type is it? If it is already Data then you don't need to do anything with it I assume.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson but it is coming in encoding formate and then I am decoding .

Comment: Did you try decoding it directly? `JSONDecoder().decode(forget_Base.self, from: responseValue)` ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson already tried not working.

Comment: "not working" meaning what? And please add some proper error handling by printing the actual error in your `catch`, `catch { print(error) }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I already mention all the things and Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message it's simply

```
let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(forget_Base.self, from: Data(responseValue.utf8))
```

A type cast to `Decoder` is pointless anyway.

And please conform to the naming convention, `forget_Base` is horrible, name it `ForgetBase`

Comment: tried and getting this error  ----- (Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data')

Comment: Then it's `Data(responseValue.utf8`). I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use responseValue as it is.
Here's the code:
change the following

```
let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(forget_Base.self, from: Data(from: responseValue.utf8 as! Decoder))
```

to

```
let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(forget_Base.self, from:responseValue)
```

Comment: You're right. I should have tweaked the concerned line only. My bad! Edited as per your suggestion @JoakimDanielson